# How can I use resorce for Description attribute for a property?

Tags: c#, attributes, resx

I have property below:

```
 [Description("Name Of Person")]
 public string FirstName {get; set;}
```

is there any way to use resource for "Name of person" statement similar below:

```
 [Description(MyResource.FirstName)]
 public string FirstName {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is you use resource files. The following article describes how to use them from code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542.aspx

But i think that visual studio has pretty good designer for that purpose.